# Retrieve records from Multiple tables using Join

Tags: mysql

I want to retrieve records from multiple tables using Join operation.

See below is my table:

```
Table Name : country

+--------+-------------
| Field  | Type
+--------+-------------
| c_id   | int(5)
| c_name | varchar(30)
+--------+-------------

Table Name : company

+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| c_id     | int(5)      |
| com_id   | int(5)      |
| com_name | varchar(30) |
+----------+-------------+

Table Name : branch

+----------+-------------+
| Field    | Type        |
+----------+-------------+
| com_id   | int(5)     |
| b_id     | int(5)     |
| b_name   | varchar(30)|
| com_name | varchar(20)|
+----------+-------------+
```

My result should be like bellow :

```
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
| com_name    | c_name      |   b_id      |   b_name    |
+-------------+-------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Please Help me......

Comment: So is it about MySQL or SQL-Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made the assumption that this is SQL Server and it didn't look like there was a where clause requirement so I provided this query for that. If you need for mysql please update question.

```
 Select co.com_name,c.c_name,b.b_id,b.b_name
 from Country c
 inner join Company co on c.c_id = co.c_id
 inner join branch b on co.com_id = b.com_id
```